# Access query using * and sort criteria on columns - how to make field show just column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

#### What I am doing

I have a query in Access which as SQL view of:

```
SELECT Projects.*, Projects.MySortField
FROM Projects
ORDER BY Projects.MySortField DESC;
```

This query works fine and sorts my data correctly. It is also very, very clean to look at and to understand what is happening.

However, when I load it into my form, I have run into an unexpected problem. Prior to adding `Projects.MySortField` and the associated sorting, I was able to refer to `MySortField` as follows:

```
Me.Recordset("MySortField")
```

However, now that I've added it to the sort criteria, the query returns slightly difference fields as the record associated field is:

```
Me.Recordset("Projects.MySortField")
```

I refer to this somewhat often in VBA which is where problems happen.

#### What I am trying to do and why

I would like my stakeholders to be able to more easily add or modify sort criteria. Unfortunately some of these are also referred to in the code more explicitly, which means if at any time I want to add sort criteria to my list, it will also adopt the `Projects.mFieldName` syntax in the RecordSet, which means any code referring to that data will break.

This would be nice to avoid, obviously, and if it was possible to modify the query somehow to facilitate my users adding fields and not having to change any code that would be wonderful.

#### Specific Question

How can I include `Projects.*` *and* still have specific fields from that table for sorting but keep all RecordSet fields reflected as just the field name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that by having Projects.* as well as a named field, you are ending up with two output fields of the same name. I'm not sure why you feel you must use "*" instead of just explicitly naming the fields (which is generally considered the best practice) which would allow you to sort without the problem.

If you want to stick with "*" then you need to uncheck the show box in the query grid for your named fields, which will allow you to have the field explicitly enumerated for sorting or use as a criteria.

The SQL view when you do this should look like:

```
SELECT Projects.*
FROM Projects
ORDER BY Projects.MySortField DESC;
```

You can use the unchecking of the show box trick for both sorting or for doing criteria when you are using "*".

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the sort field without the qualifying table name in the SQL.  Here is what I am thinking.

```
SELECT Projects.*
FROM Projects
ORDER BY MySortField DESC;
```

Comment: You can't do this in Access, unfortunately, as it adds the `SELECT` part for the sorting field.

Comment: if you go to design view, yes but if you just close 'I think' it saves the original SQL.  This is flaky I know.

Comment: You can edit and save the SQL once you've generated it in design view.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
SELECT Projects.*
FROM Projects
ORDER BY Projects.MySortField DESC;
```

can be done.

But if you insist on adding  **, Projects.MySortField**,then

```
SELECT Projects.*, Projects.MySortField as whatever
FROM Projects
ORDER BY Projects.MySortField DESC;
```